# Trouble working with str_replace and preg_replace in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

I am having trouble with string manipulation in php. I am writing a function that with take a string parameter that has words separated with either " " or "_". I want the function to remove all non alphabetic characters and return the words separated with a "-".
This is what I have so far:

```
function cleanCategoryForUrl($strCategory){
    $newCategory = str_replace('_', '-', $strCategory); //First replacement
    echo ($newCategory);
    $newCategory = str_replace(' ', '-', $newCategory); //Second replacement
    echo ($newCategory);
    $newCategory = preg_replace('/[^a-z-]/i', '', $strCategory); //Final replacement
    echo ($newCategory);
    return $newCategory;
}
```

The first and second replacements will get make the words separated with "-" instead of " " or "_". The final replacement will get red of all characters that are not alphabetic or a "-".

But when I test the code, I get unexpected results after the final replacement.

With an input of "Home_Health" I get this printed:

```
Home-Health
Home-Health
HomeHealth
```

The first two outputs are as expected, but third one removed the "-" (which shouldn't have happened). I suspect something is wrong with my regex pattern, but it words fine when I test it on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/. I am new to using regex and cant figure out what is wrong. Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems fine but just a problem in parameter you passing in preg_replace.
Instead of passing $newCategory you are passing $strCategory.

Just try with below one,

```
function cleanCategoryForUrl($strCategory){
    $newCategory = str_replace('_', '-', $strCategory); //First replacement
    echo ($newCategory."<br/>");
    $newCategory = str_replace(' ', '-', $newCategory); //Second replacement
    echo ($newCategory."<br/>");
    $newCategory = preg_replace('/[^a-z-]/i', '', $newCategory); //Final replacement
    echo ($newCategory."<br/>");
    return $newCategory;
}
```

Or else you can use this one.

```
function cleanCategoryForUrl($strCategory){
    $newCategory = preg_replace('/[_ ]/', '-', $strCategory); //Final replacement
    $newCategory = preg_replace('/[^a-z-]/i', '', $newCategory); //Final replacement
    echo ($newCategory."<br/>");
    return $newCategory;
}
```

Hope this will help,

Thanks!

Hussain.

Comment: OMG I cant believe I made such a mistake. I meant to pass $newCategory to preg_replace. All that time I was checking the pattern but never checked to make sure the other parameters were correct. Thanks for pointing it out.